# Cambiar contenido de un boton desde C#

Tags: c#, wpf, botón, xaml, binding

tengo problemas al intentar cambiar el texto de un botón que esta dentro de un `UserControl`.
Necesito crear los `Button` dinámicamente y para probar estoy pasandole en el constructor el nombre que quiero que tenga el propio `Button`.
¿Que hago mal?

***Definicion del UserControl:***

```
public partial class VmWareButton : UserControl
{
    private string _Text;

    public VmWareButton(string nombre)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Text = nombre;
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _Text; }
        set { _Text = value; }
    }

}

<UserControl x:Class="Namensänderung.UserControls.VmWareButton"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Namensänderung.UserControls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid>
    <Button Margin="0,4,0,0" Height="28" Content="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontFamily="Arial">

    </Button>
</Grid>
```

***Creacion/Llamada del UserControl***

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        spExpander.Children.Add(new VmWareButton("asdfasd"));
        spExpander.Children.Add(new VmWareButton("asdfasd"));
        spExpander.Children.Add(new VmWareButton("asdfasd"));
        spExpander.Children.Add(new VmWareButton("asdfasd"));
        spExpander.Children.Add(new VmWareButton("asdfasd"));

    }
```

Sin embargo, no veo que los contenidos cambien...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que el problema viene por la manera de hacer el `Binding` pero no se muy bien como debo enlazar el dato.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Y que es lo que deseas que suceda con el nombre que le pasas al constructor?. ¿Acaso lo que deseas es que ese texto se muestre en cada instancia que has creado del UserControl?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que deseas es que el texto que pasas como argumento al constructor se muestre en cada instancia que has creado del `UserControl`, tendrás que dibujar el texto, pues en el código que muestras, solo has agregado el nombre a la propiedad `Text` de tu `UserControl`, pero no has hecho nada con ella; te coloco a continuación, una variante de como podrías dibujar el texto, para que tu `UserControl` lo muestre.

```
public partial class VmWareButton : UserControl
{
    private string _Text;
    //Declarar variable para almacenar el Grafico del Control
    private Graphics Grfc;
    //Declarar variable para almacenar la fuente con que se dibujará el texto
    private Font Fte;
    public VmWareButton(string nombre)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Text = nombre;
        //Crear la variable para almacenar el Grafico del Control
        this.Grfc = this.CreateGraphics();
        //Crear la variable para almacenar la fuente con que se dibujará el texto
        this.Fte = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8F,
            System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));

    }
    //Sobrecargar la Propiedad Text
    public override string Text
    {
        get { return _Text; }
        set { _Text = value; }
    }

    //Evento  Resize, para crear la variable Grfc, cada ves que cambien la diemnsiones
    private void VmWareButton_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Grfc = this.CreateGraphics();
    }
    //Evanto Paint Dibujar el texto sobre el control
    private void VmWareButton_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
         this.Grfc.DrawString(this._Text, Fte, Brushes.Black, new PointF(2, this.Height / 2));
    }

}
```

---

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**
Para el caso en que hayas creado un botón alojado en tu `UserControl`, el texto quedaría de la siguiente manera, estoy asumiendo que tu botón se llama `Buton1` y lógicamente no seria necesario dibujar tu texto, pues control Buton, lo haria, solo tienes que pasarle la propiedad `Text`

```
public partial class VmWareButton : UserControl
{
    //Esta variable no seria necesaria
    //private string _Text;

    public VmWareButton(string nombre)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Text = nombre;
    }
    //No dejar de Sobrecargar la Propiedad Text
    public override string Text
    {
        get { return this.Buton1.Text; }
        set { this.Buton1.Text = value; }
    }

}
```

Comment: pero si ya existe un boton en el user control, es necesario dibujar a mano el texto? no basta con pasarselo al boton que esta dentro del control?

Comment: @gbianchi Pero en tu código, no se hace referencia a ningún botón, alojado en tu `UserControl`, si creaste un botón solo tendrías que asignarle el texto que deseas mostrar en a la propiedad `Text` de tu botón; pero eso no lo has hecho en el código que mostraste en tu pregunta. Para hacer eso no te haría falta la variable `private string _Text;` que declaras, suponiendo que tu botón se llame `Buton1` la propiedad Text de tu `UserControl`, quedaría de la siguiente forma  public override string Text
    {
        get { return Buton1.Text; }
        set {  Buton1.Text = value; }
    }

Comment: @gbianchi Edité la respuesta para adecuarla al caso en que hayas creado un `Buton` interno que asumí se llama `Buton1`, si no es así solo tienes que sustituir en el código este por el nombre de tu `Buton`.

Comment: Yo no soy quien pregunto. Pero la pregunta tiene el xalm del uc con un boton

Comment: @gbianchi Sea quien sea que haya hecho la pregunta, lo que si está claro es que en el código de la clase `class VmWareButton : UserControl`no hay ninguna referencia a un control `Buton`, y en cualquier caso, el botón que quieras hospedar en tu `UserControl`, no es predeterminado, hay que crearlo y agregarle código a tu `UserControl` para otorgarle funcionalidad. Si no conoces el código que no se mostró en la pregunta, entonces no podemos solucionar el problema, el objetivo de este sitio es que los usuarios intercambien para resolver los problemas a que se enfrentan.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo. Y por eso te digo que en su codigo si esta el xalm y hay un boton alli... fijate en la pregunta... asi que supongo que le querra asignar el texto a ese boton...